# DynamicLinq build select with subquery

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I dynamically build select with [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core). I want to add another column (subquery).  Is this possible?

I need to get same results as this query:

```
var test = this.DbContext.Countries.Select(t => new
{
    t.Id,
    t.ISOCode,
    lookup = t.Translates.Where(t2 => t2.LangISOCode=="ENG").Select(t2 => t2.Title).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToArray();
```

I get this far:

```
this.DbContext.Countries.Select("new(Id,ISOCode)").ToDynamicArrayAsync()
```

but not sure how to add additional subquery column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
await this.DbContext.Countries.Select("new(Id,ISOCode,Translates.Where(LangISOCode=\"SLV\").Select(Title).FirstOrDefault() as translates)").ToDynamicArrayAsync();
```

I found solution by combing code from source tests ([select](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/QueryableTests.Select.cs#L25), [where](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/QueryableTests.Where.cs), [firstordefault](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/QueryableTests.FirstOrDefault.cs)).